# Unable to check/uncheck the checkbox by selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

Xpath is showing 1 of 1 and unable to check the checkbox. HTML code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="false" id="title64_hidden">
```

Webdriver is able click on the checkbox but check box is not selecting

Comment: Can you show some HTML or Page url  ?

Comment: Do not update the Question Heading , try updating question body with more relevant information such as what code you tried and what exactly did not work

Comment: Please show a link to that page or at least the entire HTML page code. Single element is not enough

Comment: <div class="fpColValue">
 <div class="booleanValueSelector valueSelector" id="title64">
   <div onmousedown="valueSelectorOnEnter('title62' , $('title64_check'), 'focus')" class="collapsed falseValue" id="title64_check" selector="selector">
    <input type="hidden" value="false" id="title64_hidden">
This is the html code for a chekbox. Now i need to click on the checkbox having this html code